# Apex inputfield and outputfield showing different values after rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a class Members__c which has a lookup field to User. I'm dynamically creating rows for this class and re-rendering the output table when add/remove row happens.

I'm facing a strange issue where deleteRow is not rendering the table properly. I checked the debug logs and delete seems to work fine. However, the input field is not getting rendered properly. Strangely enough, if I print the lookup field as an output field, I see the correct values.

Here is my VF page :

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Members" columns="1" rendered="true">
    <apex:panelGrid width="80%" style="padding-left:120px" id="filterpanel">
<apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!members}" var="member" id="memberTable2" >

           <tr><apex:column ><apex:outputText style="width:150px" value="{!rowNumber}" rendered="true"/></apex:column></tr>
               <!-- <tr><apex:column headerValue="Id" ><apex:inputField value="{!member.Name}" required="true"/></apex:column></tr> -->
                <tr><apex:column headerValue="User inputfield" ><apex:inputField id="currfield" value="{!member.User__c}"/></apex:column>  </tr>
                <tr><apex:column headerValue="User outputfield" ><apex:outputField value="{!member.User__c}"/></apex:column></tr>

        <tr>
            <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="filterpanel" immediate="true">
                    <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </tr>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:commandButton style="float:right" value="Add Row" id="addButton" immediate="true" action="{!addrow}" rerender="filterpanel" rendered="true"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The apex class snippet:

```
//Creates a new member
public void addrow(){
    Member__c newmember = new Member__c();
    members.add(newMember);
}


public void deleteRow(){
    Member__c removed = members.get(rowIndex);
    if(deletedMembers == null) {

        deletedMembers = new List<Member__c>();
    }
    deletedMembers.add(removed);
    members.remove(rowIndex);
}
```

Here is the output after two deletes:

![output after delete row][[http://imgur.com/a/tlvfm]](https://imgur.com/a/tlvfm])

note that after deleting 'Some one' user, the user inputfield outputs 'Some one' whereas the same outputfield points to 'Security User'

Would appreciate any help/pointers here.

Comment: Your image is not shown here

Comment: some thoughts: (1) I tend to use controller maps of ids to records so the VF page need only pass the `Member__c.Id` being deleted and the javascript and apex variables can be omitted and (2) this problem tends to look like the setter for the inputField is transmitted to the controller.  Look at the debug logs and see how the setters are being invoked in the context of the `deleteRow` action method.

Comment: Sorry, the imgur link defaults to https whereas I got an http link for the images. New to imgur and not sure how to store the image and get an https link

Comment: @cropedy, I added a debug statement in the setter method for the members variable. I see the getter being called often but no calls to the setter. Is it because it is accessing a particular index in members? Not sure how to add a debug for that